# Eclipse Workspace name persists

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to change my Workspace name and I did so at 'Workspace name' textbox at Window > Preferences > General > Workspace.

I renamed the actual folder too with the new name.

But when I try to switch to this new workspace from a different workspace at File > Switch Workspace, it still shows old workspace name.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the workspace from Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces